# Set specific Wifi channel in Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, kde, manjaro

I am trying to make the switch from Windows 10 to Manjaro KDE, and the last thing on my check-off list is setting my WiFi to a certain channel.

There is a community router for three houses, without access.  It has a big outdoor antennae, and the same name for all channels. The channel I need is 153.  How do I set that in Manjaro?

Comment: So is your question how to set the channel on Linux?  Which distro (KDE is just the desktop environment)?

Comment: Yes I would like to to set a specific wifi channel and I am in kde. (Manjaro)   If not possible I would also not mind disabling the 2.4 all the way and that would force it to connect to the 5 ghz channel. the network has the same name with channel 1,6,11 for 2.4 ghz and 153 for 5ghz. I need 153 and 149 but if I could just lock to 153 thats fine too.